# Retornar variável dentro do if para passar pra view

Tags: php, html, laravel

eu quero escrever um código de forma que o usuário escolha um ID num combobox e informações especificas são mostradas no HTML, mas eu preciso fazer um if pra saber se o fornecedor escolhido é o A, B ou C, mas nao consigo retornar a variável dentro do if pra passar pra view.

segue Controller:

```
    $id = DB::table('rcis')->pluck('rci_id');
    $rciid = $request->input('idrci');

    $teste = DB::table('rcis')->select('fornecedor_escolhido')->where('rci_id', '=', $rciid)->get(); 

    if($teste=='[{"fornecedor_escolhido":"A"}]'){
        $rci = DB::table('rcis')
        ->join('colaboradors', 'rcis.fk_colaborador', '=', 'colaboradors.colaborador_id')
        ->join('centrocustos', 'rcis.fk_centrocusto', '=', 'centrocustos.centrocusto_id')
        ->join('status_rcis', 'rcis.fk_status_rci', '=', 'status_rcis.status_rci_id')
        ->join('fornecedor_detalhes', 'fornecedor_detalhes.fk_rcid', '=', 'rcis.rci_id')

        ->select('rcis.observacoes',
            'rcis.data_rci',
            'colaboradors.nome_colab',
            'centrocustos.cod_centrocusto',
            'status_rcis.descricao_status',
            'rcis.fornecedor_escolhido',
            'fornecedor_detalhes.valortotalcompra',
            'fornecedor_detalhes.prazo_entrega')
        ->where('rci_id', '=', $rciid)
        ->where('rcis.fornecedor_escolhido','=', 'A')            
        ->wherecolumn('rcis.fornecedor_escolhido','=', 'fornecedor_detalhes.letra')
        ->get();
    }

    elseif($teste=='[{"fornecedor_escolhido":"B"}]'){
        $rci = DB::table('rcis')
        ->join('colaboradors', 'rcis.fk_colaborador', '=', 'colaboradors.colaborador_id')
        ->join('centrocustos', 'rcis.fk_centrocusto', '=', 'centrocustos.centrocusto_id')
        ->join('status_rcis', 'rcis.fk_status_rci', '=', 'status_rcis.status_rci_id')
        ->join('fornecedor_detalhes', 'fornecedor_detalhes.fk_rcid', '=', 'rcis.rci_id')

        ->select('rcis.observacoes',
            'rcis.data_rci',
            'colaboradors.nome_colab',
            'centrocustos.cod_centrocusto',
            'status_rcis.descricao_status',
            'rcis.fornecedor_escolhido',
            'fornecedor_detalhes.valortotalcompra',
            'fornecedor_detalhes.prazo_entrega')
        ->where('rci_id', '=', $rciid)
        ->where('rcis.fornecedor_escolhido','=', 'B')            
        ->wherecolumn('rcis.fornecedor_escolhido','=', 'fornecedor_detalhes.letra')
        ->get(); 
    }

    elseif($teste=='[{"fornecedor_escolhido":"C"}]'){
        $rci = DB::table('rcis')
        ->join('colaboradors', 'rcis.fk_colaborador', '=', 'colaboradors.colaborador_id')
        ->join('centrocustos', 'rcis.fk_centrocusto', '=', 'centrocustos.centrocusto_id')
        ->join('status_rcis', 'rcis.fk_status_rci', '=', 'status_rcis.status_rci_id')
        ->join('fornecedor_detalhes', 'fornecedor_detalhes.fk_rcid', '=', 'rcis.rci_id')

        ->select('rcis.observacoes',
            'rcis.data_rci',
            'colaboradors.nome_colab',
            'centrocustos.cod_centrocusto',
            'status_rcis.descricao_status',
            'rcis.fornecedor_escolhido',
            'fornecedor_detalhes.valortotalcompra',
            'fornecedor_detalhes.prazo_entrega')
        ->where('rci_id', '=', $rciid)
        ->where('rcis.fornecedor_escolhido','=', 'C')            
        ->wherecolumn('rcis.fornecedor_escolhido','=', 'fornecedor_detalhes.letra')
        ->get();
    }

    return view ('/escolherci', ['id'=>$id, 'rci'=>$rci]);    
}
```

e a view.blade:

```
<h3>Escolha uma chave estrangeira para selecionar uma RCI</h3>
<!--ID DROPDOWN-->
    <label  for="idrci">Chave estrangeira: </label>
    <select class="form-control"  type="text" name="idrci" id="idrci">
    @foreach ($id as $idr)
    {
     <option value="{{ $idr }}">{{ $idr }}</option>
    }
    @endforeach
    </select><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Salvar"> </button>
</form>

@foreach($rci as $rc)

    Requisitante: {{$rc->nome_colab}}<br><br>
    Centro de custo: {{$rc->cod_centrocusto}}<br><br>
    Descrição: {{$rc->observacoes}}<br><br>
    Status RCI: {{$rc->descricao_status}}<br><br>        
    Valor total da compra: {{$rc->valortotalcompra}}<br><br>
    Prazo entrega: {{$rc->prazo_entrega}}<br><br>

@endforeach
```

no formulário HTML é só pra o controller pegar o ID o target=_self pra mostrar na mesma página. Preciso retornar essa variável dentro dos ifs $rci pra view

Comment: Você está retornando só a variavel $rci e está saindo do controller.
Você deve tirar o return $rci de dentro dos ifs para que o controller chegue na ultima linha do return

Comment: essa foi só uma das tentativas que fiz, o problema é que nao consigo pegar a variavel dentro do if pra jogar na view

Comment: ao fim de cada if digite dd($rci) para ver se ele está entrando em algum if

Comment: fiz, ele retorna os valores que quero em forma de json.

Comment: mas você usa os dados em formato de json mesmo? tente alterar a ultima linha para return view('/escolherci', ['id'=>$id, 'rci'=>json_decode($rci)])

Comment: fazendo isso que voce falou ele da na mesma "Undefined variable: rci" e não, eu quero passar os dados pro HTML que postei , pois ainda vou fazer mais coisas com a página

Comment: faça o dd($rci) antes do return view pra ver. E a variavel $id ele está encontrando no blade?

Comment: @AdemilsonSantanadaSilva fiz o dd e ainda mesmo erro  Undefined variable: rci na linha onde dei o dd, a variável id ele pega que é pra popular o combobox

Comment: Voce quer pegar os resultados do rci de acordo com o que você seleciona no primeiro combobox, carregando isso dinamicamente?

Comment: isso, usuário escolhe o id e ele vai carregar os dados na view

Comment: se entrar em /escolherci?idrci=2  com o id da certo, ele mostra a página como é pra ser, mas não sei porque se eu entrar em só /escolherci nao da certo

Comment: entendi, agora ta claro o erro. Assim, não tem como fazer ele não atualizar a pagina só com php. Você tem que usar ajax no jquery se quiser fazer sem atualizar a pagina

Comment: para evitar o erro, antes do foreach q vc dá no $rci no blade, coloque um if(isset($rci)) e coloque o foreach dentro

Comment: e depois voce pode fazer que ao selecionar o item do primeiro combobox, voce redireciona novamente para essa mesma pagina passando o idrci como parametro na url, igual voce mostrou no caso em que dá certo

Comment: É isso @AdemilsonSantanadaSilva deu certo com o if(isset($rci) antes do foreach, vou atualizar a pergunta, mto obrigada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

blade:

```
<h3>Escolha uma chave estrangeira para selecionar uma RCI</h3>
<!--ID DROPDOWN-->
    <label  for="idrci">Chave estrangeira: </label>
    <select class="form-control"  type="text" name="idrci" id="idrci">
    @foreach ($id as $idr)
    {
     <option value="{{ $idr }}">{{ $idr }}</option>
    }
    @endforeach
    </select><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Salvar"> </button>
</form>
    @if(isset($rci))
    @foreach($rci as $rc)

    <b>Requisitante:</b>   {{$rc->nome_colab}}<br><br>
    <b>Centro de custo:</b>  {{$rc->cod_centrocusto}}<br><br>
    <b>Descrição:</b>  {{$rc->observacoes}}<br><br>
    <b>Status RCI:</b>  {{$rc->descricao_status}}<br><br>        
    <b>Valor total da compra:</b> {{$rc->valortotalcompra}}<br><br>
    <b>Prazo entrega:</b>  {{$rc->prazo_entrega}}<br><br>

    @endforeach
    @endif
```

controller:

```
    $id = DB::table('rcis')->pluck('rci_id');
    $rciid = $request->input('idrci');

    $teste = DB::table('rcis')->select('fornecedor_escolhido')->where('rci_id', '=', $rciid)->get(); 

    if($teste=='[{"fornecedor_escolhido":"A"}]'){
        $rci = DB::table('rcis')
        ->join('colaboradors', 'rcis.fk_colaborador', '=', 'colaboradors.colaborador_id')
        ->join('centrocustos', 'rcis.fk_centrocusto', '=', 'centrocustos.centrocusto_id')
        ->join('status_rcis', 'rcis.fk_status_rci', '=', 'status_rcis.status_rci_id')
        ->join('fornecedor_detalhes', 'fornecedor_detalhes.fk_rcid', '=', 'rcis.rci_id')

        ->select('rcis.observacoes',
            'rcis.data_rci',
            'colaboradors.nome_colab',
            'centrocustos.cod_centrocusto',
            'status_rcis.descricao_status',
            'rcis.fornecedor_escolhido',
            'fornecedor_detalhes.valortotalcompra',
            'fornecedor_detalhes.prazo_entrega')
        ->where('rci_id', '=', $rciid)
        ->where('rcis.fornecedor_escolhido','=', 'A')            
        ->wherecolumn('rcis.fornecedor_escolhido','=', 'fornecedor_detalhes.letra')
        ->get();
        return view('/escolherci', ['id'=>$id, 'rci'=>$rci]);

    }

    elseif($teste=='[{"fornecedor_escolhido":"B"}]'){
        $rci = DB::table('rcis')
        ->join('colaboradors', 'rcis.fk_colaborador', '=', 'colaboradors.colaborador_id')
        ->join('centrocustos', 'rcis.fk_centrocusto', '=', 'centrocustos.centrocusto_id')
        ->join('status_rcis', 'rcis.fk_status_rci', '=', 'status_rcis.status_rci_id')
        ->join('fornecedor_detalhes', 'fornecedor_detalhes.fk_rcid', '=', 'rcis.rci_id')

        ->select('rcis.observacoes',
            'rcis.data_rci',
            'colaboradors.nome_colab',
            'centrocustos.cod_centrocusto',
            'status_rcis.descricao_status',
            'rcis.fornecedor_escolhido',
            'fornecedor_detalhes.valortotalcompra',
            'fornecedor_detalhes.prazo_entrega')
        ->where('rci_id', '=', $rciid)
        ->where('rcis.fornecedor_escolhido','=', 'B')            
        ->wherecolumn('rcis.fornecedor_escolhido','=', 'fornecedor_detalhes.letra')
        ->get();
        return view('/escolherci', ['id'=>$id, 'rci'=>$rci]);

    }

    elseif($teste=='[{"fornecedor_escolhido":"C"}]'){
        $rci = DB::table('rcis')
        ->join('colaboradors', 'rcis.fk_colaborador', '=', 'colaboradors.colaborador_id')
        ->join('centrocustos', 'rcis.fk_centrocusto', '=', 'centrocustos.centrocusto_id')
        ->join('status_rcis', 'rcis.fk_status_rci', '=', 'status_rcis.status_rci_id')
        ->join('fornecedor_detalhes', 'fornecedor_detalhes.fk_rcid', '=', 'rcis.rci_id')

        ->select('rcis.observacoes',
            'rcis.data_rci',
            'colaboradors.nome_colab',
            'centrocustos.cod_centrocusto',
            'status_rcis.descricao_status',
            'rcis.fornecedor_escolhido',
            'fornecedor_detalhes.valortotalcompra',
            'fornecedor_detalhes.prazo_entrega')
        ->where('rci_id', '=', $rciid)
        ->where('rcis.fornecedor_escolhido','=', 'C')            
        ->wherecolumn('rcis.fornecedor_escolhido','=', 'fornecedor_detalhes.letra')
        ->get();
        return view('/escolherci', ['id'=>$id, 'rci'=>$rci]);
    }

    return view('/escolherci', ['id'=>$id]);
```